# GoJS Genogram, Change node order by custom

Tags: javascript, gojs

In the example of 
[GoJS Genogram](https://gojs.net/latest/samples/genogram.html)

I only know how to custom node shapes, link styles and something about view. but I could not figure out how could I participate in make order of nodes, like: I added a property about age for all family and want to order by age in same generation when gojs ploting.

This is
[My Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Dowen/1tuhn0v6/)

How can I change older family to left automatically, I thought key order could save my problem, but actually key wasn't help on anything.

ex. older brother -> order sister -> me -> young... -> young...

Below is what I mainly modified from GoJS Genogram Example.

```
[
  { key: 0, n: "Father", s: "M", ux: 1, a: ["C", "F", "K", "X"] },
  { key: 1, n: "Mother", s: "F", a: ["B", "H", "K", "X"] },
  { key: 4, n: "Me", s: "M", m: 1, f: 0, ux: 5, a: ["ME"] },
  { key: 5, n: "Wife", s: "F", vir: 5, a: ["C"] },
  { key: 2, n: "Old Brother", s: "M", m: 1, f: 0, a: ["E", "H", "X"] },
  { key: 3, n: "Old Sister", s: "F", m: 1, f: 0, a: ["B", "H", "L"] },
  { key: 6, n: "Young Sister", s: "F", m: 1, f: 0, a: ["C"] },
  { key: 7, n: "Young Brother", s: "M", m: 1, f: 0, a: ["C", "I"] },
  { key: 8, n: "Son", s: "M", m: 4, f: 5, vir: 9, a: ["E"] },
  { key: 9, n: "Son's wife", s: "F", vir: 8, a: ["B", "H"] },
  { key: 10, n: "Daughter", s: "M", m: 4, f: 5, a: ["E", "G"] },
  { key: 11, n: "Daughter's husband", s: "F", vir: 10, a: ["B", "J"] },
  { key: 12, n: "grandson", s: "F", m: 8, f: 9, a: ["J"] },
  { key: 13, n: "grand daughter", s: "M", m: 8, f: 9, a: ["B", "H"] },
  { key: 14, n: "grandson", s: "F", m: 10, f: 11, a: ["E", "G"] },
  { key: 15, n: "grand daughter", s: "M", m: 10, f: 11, a: ["F", "H"] },
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is to mix all of the people of the same generation together so that they are sorted by age, even though they belong to different parents.

The GenogramLayout currently is implemented with (and actually inherits from) **LayeredDigraphLayout**, which is designed to re-order the nodes in order to reduce link crossings.  It does not support ordering of all of the nodes in each layer, which would result in huge numbers of crossing links.

Sorry.